# is my malloc array changing unintended values?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

This is probably me being a noob, but....

I am trying to use a 2D array that is dynamically allocated. I followed the method shown [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444) where they do a workaround using a single dimension array that is "Row x Column" in size.

When I'm doing some testing, I fill all positions of the array with the number 2, and then I've been accessing single positions and changing them to a 9 just to see where A(1), A(2), A(3), etc. would be with respect to the single dimension.

Everything goes as expected until I try to modify A[5], when I do, two positions of the array are being overwritten instead of just 5. Any ideas on what's going on?

By the way, addressing the positions of the array through "A[5] and A[4]" vs "*(A+5) and *(A+4)" gives the same results.

Thanks for any help! :)

This:

```
int main()
{
    int dim1, dim2, row, column, i=0;
    scanf("%d",&dim1);
    scanf("%d",&dim2);
    printf("dim1=%d dim2=%d\n", dim1, dim2);

    int *A;
    A=(int* )malloc(dim1*dim2*sizeof(int));
    for(row=0; row<dim1; row++)
    {
            for(column=0; column<dim2; column++)
            {
                    A[(row*dim1)+column]=2;
                    i++;
            }
    }
    printf("Before assignment\n");
    *(A+5)=9;//<<<<<<<-THIS IS WHERE I AM ACCESSING THE ARRAY
    printf("after assignment\n");


    for(row=0; row<dim1; row++)
    {
            for(column=0; column<dim2; column++)
            {
                   printf("%d ", A[(row*dim1)+column]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Results in this:
[Accessing A[5]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U13C.jpg)

But This:

```
int main()
{
    int dim1, dim2, row, column, i=0;
    scanf("%d",&dim1);
    scanf("%d",&dim2);
    printf("dim1=%d dim2=%d\n", dim1, dim2);

    int *A;
    A=(int* )malloc(dim1*dim2*sizeof(int));
    for(row=0; row<dim1; row++)
    {
            for(column=0; column<dim2; column++)
            {
                    A[(row*dim1)+column]=2;
                    i++;
            }
    }
    printf("Before assignment\n");
    *(A+4)=9;//<<<<<<<-THIS IS WHERE I AM ACCESSING THE ARRAY
    printf("after assignment\n");


    for(row=0; row<dim1; row++)
    {
            for(column=0; column<dim2; column++)
            {
                   printf("%d ", A[(row*dim1)+column]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Results in this:
[Accessing A[4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49TMA.jpg)

Comment: `A[(row*dim1)+column]` → `A[(row*dim2)+column]`. Name your variables with meaningful names (eg: width and height here), that will avoid such mistakes.

Comment: @spectras: I would say this is a fairly common mistake, even with well-named variables.

Comment: thank you both! Yes, I was multiplying by the number of rows instead of number of columns. The problem was in the print section, not where the "2" is being filled, changing dim1 to dim2 in the for loop that filled the array with "2" didn't make any difference, but in the print array it did. 
I've also changed the names as adviced :)

Comment: You might want to update to 21th century C. Then you can write `int (*A)[dim2] = malloc(sizeof(int[dim1][dim2]));` And access `A` as `A[row][column] = x;`. Saves you from all these icky, buggy calculations.

Comment: @Lundin: I tried going with that method too but I had trouble passing the array around to other functions. Can you give an example on how would you pass that array by reference to be used all around the program?

Comment: @Miguel You will need to write a pointer to an array pointer, in this case `int (**A)[n]` where `n` is another parameter to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the incorrect address.

```
A[(row*dim1)+column]=2;
       ^^^^
```

This `dim1` should be `dim2`.

```
A[(row*dim2)+column]=2;
```

Recall that `dim1` is the number of rows, and `dim2` is the number of columns. It may be helpful to name them `nrows` and `ncols` or some other descriptive name.

```
A[(row*ncols)+column]=2;
```

Comment: For anybody trying to find more explanation of the answer, see the comment section of the question.

Comment: I strongly second using nrows and ncols with row and column index. dim1,dim2 etc. may make sense with indices such as x,y,z... or i,j,k... etc,  that have a natural order to them.